# 'pdfseparate': Format output file name as page number with leading zeroes

Tags: unix, pdf, poppler

[pdfseparate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/pdfseparate.1.html) requires to specify `%d` as PDF-page-pattern which is replaced by the page number.

`$ pdfseparate CFL_1115_ISSUU.pdf cfl-%d.pdf` works. It sets separated output file names as `cfl-1.pdf, cfl-2.pdf, ..., cfl-10.pdf` etc.

Now I need to add leading `0` to fix the file name string length. So when I try to use formatting characters in command `$ pdfseparate CFL_1115_ISSUU.pdf cfl-%04d.pdf`, it gives error `Syntax Error: 'cfl-%04d.pdf' must contain '%d' if more than one page should be extracted`

Can anybody suggest if such formatting is possible?

Comment: Which version of Poppler/pdfseparate are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On my system (Mac OS X), using the most recent version of Poppler, v0.42.0, this command works as expected:

```
$ pdfseparate -l 10 PDF32000_2008.pdf cfl-%04d.pdf

$ ls -l cfl-*.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff    11475 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0001.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff    91252 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0002.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff  8334441 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0003.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff  8334443 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0004.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff  8334444 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0005.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff    93209 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0006.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff    89540 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0007.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff    64383 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0008.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff  8334444 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0009.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1  kp   staff   116229 23 Mär 18:58 cfl-0010.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using 0.25 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.x to fix issue I am getting up update poppler to 0.43. http://askubuntu.com/questions/722950/how-to-upgrade-poppler-utils-to-latest-version